# Anyone know best practice for using String Resources when using MVVM? Kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin, unit-testing, mvvm, android-resources

I am currently trying to write Unit tests for my code, and I am running into the problem of needing context for some of my classes (use-cases?).

Here is an example of the code:

In the class, I use the string resource to return a result.

```
class testClass {
    fun compareNumbers(numberOne: Int, numberTwo: Int, context: Context): String {
        var message = ""
        when {
            numberOne > numberTwo -> message = context.getString(R.string.numberOne)
            numberOne < numberTwo -> message = context.getString(R.string.numberTwo)
            numberOne == numberTwo -> message = context.getString(R.string.tie)
        }
        return message
    }

}
```

In the view model:

```
fun declareWinner(context: Context) {
    val result = testClass.compareNumbers(numberOne, numberTwo, context)
    updateResult(result) //updates the result to a database
}
```

I thought this would have been a good way of separating the functions from one another and not making my view model messy. Plus I need functions like the compareNumbers in many VMs, so I thought it was more reusable.
However, I am making a Unit test for this and it doesn't work as simply as I would like.

Is there a better way to do this or just try to make the context using mockito?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `testClass` shouldn't be aware of the `Context`. The role of a Use Case is to contain the business logic, but definitely not to be aware of any UI or Android Framework classes :[

You could try to inject already localized strings into this method, or even better, return an enum or sealed class and let the `ViewModel` map this enum to the actual string resource, separating the concerns: your business logic class doesn't need to know about how to present the result to the UI, and `ViewModel` doesn't need to know about the business logic, just how to map the result to the UI representation, kinda:

```kotlin
sealed class CompareResult {
    object NumberOneWins : CompareResult()
    object NumberTwoWins : CompareResult()
    object Tie : CompareResult()
}

class TestClass {
    fun compareNumbers(numberOne: Int, numberTwo: Int): CompareResult {
        return when {
            numberOne > numberTwo -> CompareResult.NumberOneWins
            numberOne < numberTwo -> CompareResult.NumberTwoWins
            else -> CompareResult.Tie
        }
    }
}

// In your ViewModel
fun declareWinner() {
    val result = testClass.compareNumbers(numberOne, numberTwo)
    val message = when (result) {
        is CompareResult.NumberOneWins -> context.getString(R.string.numberOne)
        is CompareResult.NumberTwoWins -> context.getString(R.string.numberTwo)
        is CompareResult.Tie -> context.getString(R.string.tie)
    }
    updateResult(message)
}
```

Resulting in painless unit testing without the `Context`, and `ViewModel` becomes easier to test as well - you can mock `compareNumbers` method to return a specific `CompareResult`, and then just verify that `updateResult` was called with a correct string.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I was looking for. I knew it shouldn't be aware of UI, but I forgot about the android resources part of it.